# How do I get windows 10 to read regional languages?

Tags: windows-10, windows-live

I recently upgraded to windows 10, everything is working fine but I can't read my mother language on windows 10 (Malayalam) and I can't read some languages that are showing in the Google search. I have already added that language to my PC but it won't read some of the languages.

Comment: Is this on your phone, or on a PC?

Comment: yeah i have installed win10 on my PC

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue if you are viewing/reading Malayalam font on Chrome browser. Community manager has confirmed this on the Google Chrome Help Forum.

> ...We're aware that there are some font issues with Chrome and Windows
>   10. Our team is currently investigating and they're hoping to have the font issue resolved in a later release of Chrome soon.

[Here is the direct link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/uBAYr4WmZXU)